# Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US

Tags: android

Anybody, please help me I cannot run the Android apps because of the following errors.

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>   messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US   at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)  at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1263)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:940)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1012)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:903)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:736)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:384)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [下午5:49, 2017年10月30日] +852
>   9034 6076: Information:30/10/2017, 5:10 PM - Compilation completed
>   with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5s 426ms

[Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdRiH.jpg)

Comment: I am facing similar error with Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the root directory contains the AndroidManifest.xml file. Also, the root directory must contain either the .project and .classpath files or the res/ and src/ directories.

To reload a project do Import as a Project:

1. Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
2. From the Android Studio menu click **File** > **New** > **Import Project**.

   - Alternatively, from the Welcome screen, click Import project.
3. Select the project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.

See section [Import as a Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html).
After project imported

Comment: My error experience of missing Bundle etc. caused by "Open an existing Android Studio project" rather than "Import project" described above.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but with even something more strange: the missing locale resource is en_NL which should never exist and I have no idea where this is coming from.
The language settings are en_GB and en_US.
In the Android Studio 3.0 the resources.asrc is present and seems OK.

Update:
I managed to get rid of this error. The project I'm working on is a Cordova project.

I opened the generated .apk file in Studio. That caused to error to appear.

When opening .../platforms/android in Studio everything works fine.
Perhaps not related: I also went back to version 2.3.3 of Studio. I'll keep you updated for this last point.

Update:
Studio 3.0 works also.