# Android Studio 3 and JetBrains: MissingResourceException

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I've inherited an Android app project.
I've installed Android Studio 3.0.1 and opened the project (Maybe developed with something else before..).

If I try to build the APK, I get the following error:

```
Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_GB
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_GB
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1263)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:940)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:903)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:736)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:384)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Actually inside the org folder there's nothing about JetBrains, Jps or IntelliJ.
I have only the following packages:

- apache.commons
- codehaus.jackson
- joda.time
- simpleframework.xml
- springframework

How can solve the issue?

I've read that JetBrains intelliJ is incompatible with AS3.x is it real?
BTW I don't care about IntelliJ or other plugins, I need only to recompile this app
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47012304/104891. Try reinstalling AS and if it doesn't help, try with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4.

Comment: @CrazyCoder They are similar, but none of the suggestions given there works for me. I've tried also reinstalling the whole environment, but nothing to do. Always the same problem. With IntelliJ IDEA 2017 I get several different errors. I suspect my boss has given me the code of a decompiled APK.